# Remove Nodes by ID

Tags: java

Every Object I created has an unique ID. After creating and selecting some Nodes, I store the ID's of the selected Nodes inside a List.

I want to remove the selected Nodes from another class by the unique Id I stored.

For this I tried to remove the Nodes from their parent (AnchorPane):

```
Controller.rightAnchor.getChildren().get(i).remove(customId);
```

`rightAnchor` (`@FXML public AnchorPane rightAnchor;`) is a AnchorPane inside my Controller class, `customId` is a `public String customId;` inside my class where I want to execute a Command.

```
customId = Node.selectList.get(i).getI();
```

I get the error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Controller.rightAnchor`, but I don't know why.

Is there any other way to remove my Nodes by Id?

My complete class:

```
public class CustomComponent implements Command{

    private ArrayList<Command> commandListNew = Node.commandList;
    private Node nde;
    private Command customCmd;
    public String customId;

    public void execute(){

        for(int i = 0; i < Node.selectList.size(); i++){        
            customId = Node.selectList.get(i).getI();
            //Get commands and store them to a arraylist
            customCmd = Node.selectList.get(i).getL();
            commandListNew.add(customCmd);

            Controller.rightAnchor.getChildren().get(i).remove(customId);           
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Changed my code inside `execute()`, getting now an error `The method remove() is undefined for the type Node`

```
for(int i = 0; i < Node.selectList.size(); i++){        
    customId = Node.selectList.get(i).getI();
    customCmd = Node.selectList.get(i).getL();
    commandListNew.add(customCmd);
    Controller vctr = new Controller();
    String nodeId;
    nodeId = vctr.rightAnchor.getChildren().get(i).getId();
    if(nodeId == customId){
        vctr.rightAnchor.getChildren().get(i).remove(/*What to add here?*/);
    }
}
```

What can I add to the `remove()` brackets to delete the Node which my Id belongs to?

Comment: did you try creating an instance of controller?

Comment: I tried right now, it seems to work for the static error, but I'm getting another error: `The method remove(String) is undefined for the type Node` How can I use an Id to remove a Node?

Comment: you will need to implement that method by yourself. the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html might help you with that

Comment: Solved my problem by passing Nodes inside the List.